# How to parse a non-unique positional pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have two problems connected to parsing a bit of a nasty pattern. Here are some non-sense examples:

```py
examples = [
    "",
    "red green",
    "#1# red green",
    "#1# red green <2>",
    "#1,2# red green <2,3>",
    "red green ()",
    "#1# red green (blue)",
    "#1# red green (#5# blue) <2>",
    "#1# red green (#5# blue <6>) <2>",
    "#1,2# red green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>",
    "#1,2# red (maroon) green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>",
]
```

I should say at this point that I have no control over the creation of these strings.

As you can see, basically every pattern that I would like to parse is optional. Then there are distinct parts that I would like to capture. I look at the structure of these examples as:

```
[cars] [colors] [comments] [buyers]
```

where `comments` consists of a sub-structure and may be a multiple separated by semi-colon.

```
comments: ([cars] [colors] [buyers]; ...)
```

I have created the following grammars in order to capture the content:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer

car_ref = "#" + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(integer))("cars") + "#"

buyer_ref = "<" + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(integer))("buyers") + ">"
```

My questions are then:

1. Is there a smart way (maybe through positioning) to distinguish something in parentheses that is part of the `colors` and not `comments`?
2. I have worked a bit on the problem of nested parentheses within comments. My strategy was that I would take the inner string, use `;` as a delimiter and break it up. However, I failed to execute that strategy. What I tried is:

```py
sub_comment = (
    pp.Optional(car_ref) +
    pp.Group(pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Regex(r"[^;#<>\s]")))("colors") +
    pp.Optional(buyer_ref)
)

split_comments = pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(
    pp.Group(sub_comment)("comments*"),
    delim=";"
))


def parse_comments(original, location, tokens):
    # Strip the parentheses.
    return split_comments.transformString(original[tokens[0] + 1:tokens[2] - 1])


comments = pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr()).setParseAction(parse_comments)
```

When I use this everything ends up as one continuous string, presumably because of the outer `pp.originalTextFor`.

```py
res = comments.parseString("(#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>)", parseAll=True)
```

EDIT:

Taking the last example string, I'd like to end up with an object structure that looks like:

```
{
  "cars": [1, 2],
  "colors": "red (maroon) green",
  "buyers": [2, 3],
  "comments": [
    {
      "cars": [5],
      "colors": "blue (purple)",
      "buyers": [6]
    },
    {
      "cars": [7],
      "colors": "yellow",
      "buyers": [10]
    }
  ]
}
```

So parentheses within the `colors` section should be maintained in order and just like in prose. Parentheses that introduce a `comments` section, I don't care about their order and neither about the order of individual comments.

Comment: `nested_expr` is a short-cut for when you really don't want the contents parsed, you just want to skip over them, but you have to account for nested openers and closers. Try defining a comment as a Forward(), and then use '<<=' to insert the possible contents, which can now include comments.  It also looks like comments may occur mixed in with the colors.  And the regex for colors also has to exclude `()`'s.

Comment: When you encounter a comment, does it have to maintain its order among the surrounding elements? Or can you simply report "at this level, there were these colors and these comments"? Or does it have some associativity to the preceding or following element?

Comment: Thank you for answering again :) SO is not a great medium for discussions. Can I write to you on gitter.im or open an issue on the pyparsing repo? Or do you prefer the sub-reddit?

Comment: To answer your question about associativity: The parentheses unfortunately have a double function. They can introduce a comment section or they can be used as normal parentheses in prose. Please see my edits for further clarification.

Comment: Let's try the sub-reddit if you want to pursue further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had most of the pieces in place, you were just struggling with the recursive part, where a comment could itself hold sub-structures, including more comments.

You had this as your BNF:

```
structure ::= [cars] [colors] [comments] [buyers]
cars ::= '#' integer, ... '#'
buyers ::= '<' integer, ... '>'
```

I filled in the blanks with these guesses, based on your given examples:

```
color ::= word composed of alphas
colors ::= (color | '(' color ')' )...

comments ::= '(' structure ';' ... ')'
```

I took your definitions for cars and buyers, and added colors and the recursive definition for comments. Then did a pretty rote conversion from BNF to pyparsing expressions:

```
integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer

car_ref = "#" + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(integer))("cars") + "#"
buyer_ref = "<" + pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(integer))("buyers") + ">"

# not sure if this will be sufficient for color, but it works for the given examples
color = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
colors = pp.originalTextFor(pp.OneOrMore(color | '(' + color + ')'))("colors")

# define comment placeholder so it can be used in definition of structure
comment = pp.Forward()

structure = pp.Group(pp.Optional(car_ref)
                     + pp.Optional(colors)
                     + pp.Optional(comment)("comments")
                     + pp.Optional(buyer_ref))

# now insert the definition of a comment as a delimited list of structures; this takes care of
# any nesting of comments within comments
LPAREN, RPAREN = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
comment <<= pp.Group(LPAREN + pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(structure, delim=';')) + RPAREN)
```

The tricky part is to define the contents of `comment` as a delimited list of `structure`s, and to use the `<<=` operator to insert that definition into the previously defined Forward() placeholder.

Passing your examples to `structure.runTests()` gives (default behavior is to treat Python-like comments as comments, so we have to disable this when calling runTests with your particular examples, since a leading '#' is a valid intro for cars):

```
structure.runTests(examples, comment=None)

red green
[['red green']]
[0]:
  ['red green']
  - colors: 'red green'

#1# red green
[['#', [1], '#', 'red green']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1], '#', 'red green']
  - cars: [1]
  - colors: 'red green'

#1# red green <2>
[['#', [1], '#', 'red green', '<', [2], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1], '#', 'red green', '<', [2], '>']
  - buyers: [2]
  - cars: [1]
  - colors: 'red green'

#1,2# red green <2,3>
[['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red green', '<', [2, 3], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red green', '<', [2, 3], '>']
  - buyers: [2, 3]
  - cars: [1, 2]
  - colors: 'red green'

red green ()
[['red green', [[]]]]
[0]:
  ['red green', [[]]]
  - colors: 'red green'
  - comments: [[]]
    [0]:
      []

#1# red green (blue)
[['#', [1], '#', 'red green (blue)']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1], '#', 'red green (blue)']
  - cars: [1]
  - colors: 'red green (blue)'

#1# red green (#5# blue) <2>
[['#', [1], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue']], '<', [2], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue']], '<', [2], '>']
  - buyers: [2]
  - cars: [1]
  - colors: 'red green'
  - comments: [['#', [5], '#', 'blue']]
    [0]:
      ['#', [5], '#', 'blue']
      - cars: [5]
      - colors: 'blue'

#1# red green (#5# blue <6>) <2>
[['#', [1], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue', '<', [6], '>']], '<', [2], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue', '<', [6], '>']], '<', [2], '>']
  - buyers: [2]
  - cars: [1]
  - colors: 'red green'
  - comments: [['#', [5], '#', 'blue', '<', [6], '>']]
    [0]:
      ['#', [5], '#', 'blue', '<', [6], '>']
      - buyers: [6]
      - cars: [5]
      - colors: 'blue'

#1,2# red green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>
[['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']], '<', [2, 3], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']], '<', [2, 3], '>']
  - buyers: [2, 3]
  - cars: [1, 2]
  - colors: 'red green'
  - comments: [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']]
    [0]:
      ['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>']
      - buyers: [6]
      - cars: [5]
      - colors: 'blue (purple)'
    [1]:
      ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']
      - buyers: [10]
      - cars: [7]
      - colors: 'yellow'

#1,2# red (maroon) green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>
[['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red (maroon) green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']], '<', [2, 3], '>']]
[0]:
  ['#', [1, 2], '#', 'red (maroon) green', [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']], '<', [2, 3], '>']
  - buyers: [2, 3]
  - cars: [1, 2]
  - colors: 'red (maroon) green'
  - comments: [['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>'], ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']]
    [0]:
      ['#', [5], '#', 'blue (purple)', '<', [6], '>']
      - buyers: [6]
      - cars: [5]
      - colors: 'blue (purple)'
    [1]:
      ['#', [7], '#', 'yellow', '<', [10], '>']
      - buyers: [10]
      - cars: [7]
      - colors: 'yellow'
```

If you convert all the parsed results to regular Python dicts using `asDict()` you get:

```
structure.runTests(examples, comment=None,
                   postParse=lambda test, results: results[0].asDict()
                   )

red green
{'colors': 'red green'}

#1# red green
{'cars': [1], 'colors': 'red green'}

#1# red green <2>
{'colors': 'red green', 'cars': [1], 'buyers': [2]}

#1,2# red green <2,3>
{'colors': 'red green', 'cars': [1, 2], 'buyers': [2, 3]}

red green ()
{'comments': [[]], 'colors': 'red green'}

#1# red green (blue)
{'cars': [1], 'colors': 'red green (blue)'}

#1# red green (#5# blue) <2>
{'colors': 'red green', 'cars': [1], 'comments': [{'cars': [5], 'colors': 'blue'}], 'buyers': [2]}

#1# red green (#5# blue <6>) <2>
{'colors': 'red green', 'cars': [1], 'comments': [{'colors': 'blue', 'cars': [5], 'buyers': [6]}], 'buyers': [2]}

#1,2# red green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>
{'colors': 'red green', 'cars': [1, 2], 'comments': [{'colors': 'blue (purple)', 'cars': [5], 'buyers': [6]}, {'colors': 'yellow', 'cars': [7], 'buyers': [10]}], 'buyers': [2, 3]}

#1,2# red (maroon) green (#5# blue (purple) <6>;#7# yellow <10>) <2,3>
{'colors': 'red (maroon) green', 'cars': [1, 2], 'comments': [{'colors': 'blue (purple)', 'cars': [5], 'buyers': [6]}, {'colors': 'yellow', 'cars': [7], 'buyers': [10]}], 'buyers': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: This parses the examples perfectly. Thank you for the elaborate response.